# How to disable docker swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have enabled docker swarm for local testing. Now, whenever trying to deploy using `docker-compose up` I see the following warning:

> WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.
>
> Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes
>   in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.
>
> To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

How can I disable docker swarm mode?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`docker swarm leave` is used when you want a worker node to leave from swarm , while `docker swarm leave --force` is for a manager node to leave the swarm.

Comment: I have a swarm with only one manager. I want to disable swarm mode because I don't need it and I have problem with nginx reverse proxy original client ip. So if I remove/disable the manager the containers will still works ? What happen to the network stacks and the internal ips (10.x.x.x.)?

Comment: If you have one node as manager and want to down that, then your swarm will not be functional. If you have a stack running within that swarm, that will not be active. Better approach is to remove the stack first (I am referring to `docker stack`) and then disable/remove the swarm.

Comment: Your `docker stack` or services will automatically be deleted, once your manager is down OR your quorum is not maintained. Check Leave The Swarm section in the given link https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/

Answer (score 15):

`docker swarm leave` should do the trick

Comment: I had to use `docker swarm leave --force` but it did work indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`docker swarm leave --force`

`docker network prune`

1st command to stop the swarm and then remove all the networks. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

If `docker swarm leave`
and
`docker swarm leave --force` do not working and return

```
 Error response from daemon: context deadline exceeded
```

you can remove /var/lib/docker/swarm and restart service.. for example in centos

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: This might be "draconian advice" and should be considered only with great caution.  If you actually do the `rm` command as suggested, you are effectively removing docker ... in a very clumsy way.

Comment: @MikeRobinson thank for comment! You are right, I have a mistake and fixed it. Do not use asterisk, only remove or move swarm directory